# display specific row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I need to get all data, but I need to display the "type" column in a dropdown list. Now in my table it has 2 green, 1 red and 3 white.

```
id  type_id     type        info1                   info2
1   1           green       some important data     some important data
2   1           green       some important data     some important data
3   2           red         some important data     some important data
4   3           white       some important data     some important data
5   3           white       some important data     some important data
6   3           white       some important data     some important data
```

I wanted to display this on php like this (don't worry if the codes are incomplete, I got it :D),

```
<select>
 <?php
 foreach($result as $r):
 echo '<option>'. $r['type'] . '</option>';
 endforeach;

?>
</select>
```

The problem with this is that it display all data in column(type), I need to display 1 each type_id. I can't use GROUP BY because it won't show infos that I need under that type. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at using the DISTINCT keyword in you SQL query when you retrieve the data for your dropdown

Comment: Isn't `DISTINCT` going to group the values? He doesn't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to run a second query:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $type=array();
        foreach($result as $r):
            $type[$r['type']] = '<option>'. $r['type'] . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        echo implode("", $type);
    ?>
</select>
```

If it is ok to run a second query, read [Alex Belyaev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026334/679318).

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to get list of types in your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table;
```

[Read more about MySQL SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Yes, but this requires a second query. I think he wants everything with one query only.

Comment: If target is to get all data but construct menu with distinct types by single query, he must get all the data with sql query... Then put all records from 'type' column to array and then apply array_unique to it. This will solve the problem?

Comment: This is what I'd do too. I was just pointing out that OP wouldn't want this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve all the data from table using select query.While processing query resultset you need to store all values for type field into an array and apply array_unique function to array containing type values and using foreach loop for resultant unique array you can populate dropdown list with distinct type values.This solution will eliminate utilization of second query and you will be able to access all the required data stored in table.